# Convert Numerical Fields in MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv, decimal

I have imported a CSV file where a specific column has a decimal number.

In the original excel file (before saving it to a CSV), the first number of the column shows up as 218,790. When I choose the cell, the number shows up as 218790.243077911.

In the CSV file the number shows up as 218790 and when I choose the cell it is 218,790.

When I import the file on mySQL and show the table I created, the number shows up as 218.000000000.

Here is the code I used:

```
create table Apolo_Test(
Leads decimal (15,9)
);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/SCRIPTS/file.csv'
INTO TABLE Apolo_Test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 7 ROWS
;
```

I tried updating the format with this :

```
update Apolo_Test set Leads = format(Leads, 10, 'de_DE');
```

but it did not work. I have never had a case where files had a comma before. I guess it is the UK version of numerical fields.

How is it possible to make it work on mySQL without using any MACROS in excel?

UPD:
It works but I get some warnings although I double checked the csv file and the fields :

```
create table Apolo_Test(
Ad_Group varchar(50),
Impacts int,
Leads decimal (10,3)
);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/me/Desktop/SCRIPTS/11/Adalyser.csv'
INTO TABLE Apolo_Test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 7 ROWS
(Ad_Group, Impacts, @Leads)
SET Leads = replace(@Leads, ',', '');
;

alter table Apolo_Test ADD IPL decimal (10,6) after Leads;
update Apolo_Test set IPL=Impacts/Leads;
select * from Apolo_Test;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use this syntax:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/path/to/mytable.txt' IGNORE
INTO TABLE mytable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(int_col, @float_col)
SET float_col = replace(@float_col, ',', '.');
```

For more information read [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html)

Comment: I am getting an error and I tried to change the order. It does not work :(

Comment: It seems that the problem is in the decimal (15,9) line. I get a warning of "Data Truncated, It contained more data than there were input columns". I checked that the data in the columns are not big. I also opened the .csv file in notepad++ and there are no blank columns.

Comment: @ApoloRadomer Dou you have thousand delimiter to somthing like 1.234,34?

Comment: No. It works now. I updated the code on top. I still get the warnings though. Also, when I copy pasted the code, it seems that there was a second "create table" line including the variables. But on mySQL it is not there.

Comment: create table Apolo_Test(
Ad_Group varchar(50),
Impacts int,
Leads decimal (10,3)
);
Ad_Group varchar(100),
Impacts int,
Leads decimal (15,9)
);

Comment: Also you have the comma as field seperator and as decimal separator. Maybe this causes your problem

Answer (score 1):

The thousands-separator should not matter when moving data around -- Excel internal values and CSV files and MySQL internal values do not include it.  Only "formatted" output includes it.  And you should not use formatted output for moving numbers around.

Be careful with locale, such as de_DE.

The German "218.790" is the same as English "218,790".

"218790.243077911" is likely to be what Excel had internally for the number.
"218,790" is likely to be the *English* representation on the screen; note the English thousands separator.

> In the CSV file the number shows up as 218790 and when I choose the cell it is 218,790.

What do you mean?  Perhaps that there no comma or dot in the file, itself?  But what you mean by "choose the cell"?

I can't see how to get "218.000000000" without truncation going on somewhere.

Comment: When I click on the cell on excel. The cell shows 218790 but the formula tab on top shows 218,790.

Comment: Hmmm...  That seems backwards.  The place on top where you enter the value should have the number without any commas or dots.  The cell should show it according to the formatting (Format > Cells > Numbers > ...)